# How to create a custom deserialiser for an internally tagged enum with serde in rust

Tags: rust, enums, serde

I have a bunch of entities coming out from a DynamoDB table. Each entity has a `type` field identifying what type of entity it is. The type field is a single item list with a string with the type name. This is a weird format, but it is what I have to deal with.

I succesfully implemented a custom deserialiser for the type into an enum using Serde. My current approach involves first deserialise into a simplified struct with the type field, then match on that struct type and use the proper deserialiser based on the type.

I saw that Serde supports [internally tagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#internally-tagged) enums to deserialise the rest of the fields that belong to a type in an enum with, but I don't know how to adapt my current deserialiser to opt into this feature.

For reference, this is the current deserialiser that I have:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};
use types::*;

#[derive( Debug)]
enum Type {
    Story,
    Layer,
    Unknown(String),
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Type {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s = <Vec<String>>::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let k: &str = s[0].as_str();
        Ok(match k {
            "Story" => Type::Story,
            "Layer" => Type::Layer,
            v => Type::Unknown(v.to_string()),
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
pub struct SimpleItem {
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    item_type: Type,
}
```

My ideal scenario would be this  instead:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};
use types::*;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum Type {
    Story { id: String, name: string, duration: u32 }
    Layer { id: string, layout: string },
    Unknown,
}
```

And then just use that to get the right types deserialised directly.

This is how my data may look like:
`{ type: ["Story"], ...otherFields}`

Comment: I don't think you can get serde to behave the way you'd like. You can create a custom proc macro to generate the deserializer.

Comment: Can you provide a little example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom implementation of `Deserialize` is usually the best solution for this kind of “complex” deserialization:

```rs
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Type {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<D, D::Error> {
        deserializer.deserialize_map(DeVisitor)
    }
}

struct DeVisitor;
impl<'de> de::Visitor<'de> for DeVisitor {
    type Value = Type;
    fn expecting(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("a type")
    }
    fn visit_map<A: MapAccess<'de>>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error> {
        // could use another custom Deserialize to avoid
        // allocation and improve error messages
        let type_key = map.next_key::<String>()?;
        if type_key.as_deref() != Some("type") {
            return Err(de::Error::missing_field("type"));
        }
        // You can also use a Vec<String> here so you avoid TypeField, at
        // the gain of less boilerplate but at cost of worse error messages
        let r#type = map.next_value::<TypeField>()?;
        match r#type {
            Type::Story => {
                #[derive(Deserialize)]
                struct Story {
                    id: String,
                    name: string,
                    duration: u32,
                }
                let story = Story::deserialize(MapAccessDeserializer::new(map))?;
                // Construct your Type
            } // etc
        }
    }
}

enum TypeField {
    Story,
    Layer,
    Unknown(String),
}

// The manual Deserialize implementation you had above
// goes here
```

One big limitation of the above approach is that it requires the `"type"` field to be the first field. If you want to avoid this, the easiëst approach depends on the data format. For example, with JSON it might look something like:

```rs
let mut type_field = None;
let mut data = <Vec<(String, Box<serde_json::value::RawValue)>>::new();
while let Some(key) = map.next_key()? {
    if key == "type" {
        if type_field.is_some() {
            return Err(de::Error::duplicate_field("type"));
        }
        type_field = Some(map.next_value()?);
    } else {
        data.push((key, map.next_value()?));
    }
}
// Now you can match on type_field and use MapDeserializer
// to deserialize from `data`
```

Comment: Is it advisable to define the other deserializers inline in the function like that ?

Comment: It’s fine, you can put it anywhere you want.

Comment: Did you mean to use `data.push((key, map.next_value()?));` in your second example?

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers are very complete, and correct.
However, never underestimate the convenience of keep using the default things with a little previous step.
In this particular case (I'm not saying this is something that can be applied for all similar cases) normalising the data prior to deserialising it is probably the simplest thing. The source type is almost there, the only little drawback is that it is wrapped in a useless list (this is just an artifact of the serialisation coming from a different programming language).
So, I repeat, in this particular case, dealing with this little detail is a lot easier than writing a complete new deserializer, specially because for this format is a bit complex.

So this is what I'm doing instead, unwrapping the type and then let the normal serde deserialization happen.

```rust
// Normalize the data from the DB so the "type" is just a string rather than a list with a
// single string in it.
let items = items
.iter()
.map(|item| {
    let mut item = item.to_owned();
    item.entry("type".to_owned()).and_modify(|v| {
        // if it is already a plain string, no need to unwrap
        if !v.is_s() {
            *v = v
                .as_l()
                .map_err(|_err| {
                    GetError::DataError(
                        "Expected db item 'type' field to be a list or a string",
                    )
                })
                .unwrap()
                .get(0)
                .unwrap()
                .to_owned();
        }
    });
    item
})
.collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Now you can just deserialize normally without defining any custom deserialization for the internally tagged enum:

```rust
let stories: Vec<StoryPart> = from_items(items.clone())?
```